# Bulk Api 2.0 - Get Information About All Query Jobs

Tags: bulk-api-v2

I'm using Postman to test the Bulk Api 2.0 Query endpoints.

I can create a job,  retrieve information on a single job, retrieve the job results, and delete a job.

I cannot retrieve information on all jobs.  The only difference I see between retrieving a single job and all jobs is appending the job id to the endpoint.  I'm using api v53.0.  I tested with other api versions and different Salesforce instances and receive the same error message.

Works:

```
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/jobs/query/7503I0000029c9gQAA
```

Does not work:

```
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/jobs/query
```

Error:

```
{
   "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
   "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
}
```

Any idea on why this isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: You're using the `GET` Http Method for both requests, aren't you?

Comment: For me it is returning correct data for url `curl -X GET 
  https://company.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v53.0/jobs/query`

Comment: Thanks for the information, it helped.  It is a permission issue although I'm not sure which one is needed yet.  This API account should only have read-only access.  I changed it to the admin profile and I was able to use the query endpoint to retrieve all of the bulk jobs.

Answer (score 1):

"Manage Bulk Integrations" needs to be enabled in the security profile to retrieve all bulk jobs.